# An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200

Tags: 7, ajax

I'm trying to Run the Test from Administrative User, and it bring me below Error message:

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging
>   information follows. Path:
>   /drupal7.50/batch?render=overlay&id=18&op=do StatusText: OK
>   ResponseText: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds
>   exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal7.50\includes\database\database.inc
>   on line 2204

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Increase your PHP max_execution time in php.ini

Answer (score 1):

If you check the message after **ResponseText**, it says:

> ResponseText: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds
>   exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal7.50\includes\database\database.inc
>   on line 2204

Which means the process has taken more than default [execution time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) set for PHP which is 30 seconds. You can increase the execution time by editing **[php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php)** file located at "**C:\xampp\php\php.ini**" and setting value of `max_execution_time` variable to more than 30. And then **restart Apache**.

The above change will be applicable to all site running from your local. To make it specific to particular site you can use one of the following method:

By editing **settings.php** located at "sites/default/settings.php" and adding following line:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 120);
```

Or you can also modify **[.htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)** file located in your Drupal root and add following line:

```
php_value max_execution_time 120
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the value for max_execution_time in php.ini file to be bigger than 60.
for example: max_execution_time = 300

Do not forget to restart your server.